# Setting date time format for C# stream writer when writing to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I have a new problem again. This time, it is the streamwriter causing the trouble. See, in my code, I have a data set, which I am trying to export to excel. The code basically goes through all the records in the dataset, and add them to a string. Then streamwriter object writes the whole string to a file. This is a properly working code, except one minor issue.

In all date columns, the date is in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. When it is written to excel, streamwriter converts it to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format. But, excel defaults to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format. So, half of the dates are displayed wrong, as excel is unable to find month greater than 12.

E.g. when date is 2014-10-16 00:00:00, streamwriter writes it as 10/16/2014 00:00:00. When I open the file in excel, excel interprets it as 10th day of 16th month.

Now, I know, there is a way to format the data in an excel column, but that does literally nothing.

I checked and am completely unable to find out where I am going wrong. Someone, please look at the below code and tell me what I missed.

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, System.EventArgs e )   {


        this.DeleteOldFiles( Server.MapPath( "../Temp" ) );    

        bool    bIsRowDataPresent       = false;
        bool    bIsColumnNamesPresent   = false;
        Row[]   rowReportData           = null;

        if ( Session[ "ROWOBJECT" ] != null )   {

            rowReportData       = ( Row [] )Session[ "ROWOBJECT" ];
            bIsRowDataPresent   = true;

            Session[ "ROWOBJECT" ] = null;
        }

        string[] strColumnNames = null;

        if ( Session[ "DISPLAYCOLUMNNAMES" ] != null )  {
            strColumnNames          = ( string [] )Session[ "DISPLAYCOLUMNNAMES" ];
            bIsColumnNamesPresent   = true;
        }

        string  strColumnNamesToExclude = "";

        if ( Session[ "COLUMNSTOREMOVE" ] != null ) strColumnNamesToExclude = ( string ) Session[ "COLUMNSTOREMOVE" ];

        string  strFromExcel    = ( string )Session[ Constants.FOR_EXCEL_REPORT ];

        Session[ Constants.FOR_EXCEL_REPORT ]   = null;

        string  strReport               = "";
        string  strDisplayColumn        = "";
        string  strDisplayColumnFlag    = "";

        ReportBC objReportBC = new ReportBC();

        strDisplayColumnFlag    = Convert.ToString( Session[ Constants.RPT_DISPLAY_COLUMN ] );

        if ( strDisplayColumnFlag.Trim().Equals( "" ) || strDisplayColumnFlag.Trim().Equals( Constants.CONST_NO ) ) {

            if ( bIsColumnNamesPresent )    {
                for ( int iCount = 0; iCount < strColumnNames.Length; iCount++ )    {
                    strDisplayColumn    += strColumnNames[ iCount ] + "\t";
                }
            }
        }


        if ( strFromExcel != Constants.CONST_YES && bIsRowDataPresent ) strReport   = Convert.ToString( objReportBC.ExportRowsToExcel( rowReportData, strDisplayColumn, strDisplayColumnFlag, strColumnNamesToExclude ) );
        else    {   

            string  strReportID         = ( string )Session[ Constants.REPORT_KEY_REPORTID ];
            string  strFilterCriteria   = ( string )Session[ Constants.REPORT_KEY_FILTER_CRITERIA ];

            if ( strReportID == null )  throw new FANUCApplicationException( "CM06951" );

            if ( strFilterCriteria == null )    strFilterCriteria   = "";

            if ( strFromExcel != Constants.CONST_YES )  strReport   = Convert.ToString( objReportBC.ExportToExcel( strReportID, strFilterCriteria, strDisplayColumn, strDisplayColumnFlag ) );
            else    {
                Row objRowFilter    = ( Row )Session[ Constants.FROM_ROWFILTER ];
                strReport   = Convert.ToString( objReportBC.ExportToExcelFromRowFilter( strReportID, strFilterCriteria, strDisplayColumn, strDisplayColumnFlag, objRowFilter ) );
            }               
        }

        Session.Clear();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer         = true;


        Response.ContentType    = "application/vnd.ms-excel";   
        Response.Charset        = "";

        string  strEncodingWebName  = Encoding.Default.WebName;

        CommonBQ    bqCommon    = new CommonBQ();


        // Encoding options supported are :
        // 1. ASCII -> us-ascii 
        // 2. Default
        // 3. Big5 -> big5
        // 4. UTF7 -> utf-7
        // 5. UTF8 -> utf-8
        // 6. Unicode
        // 7. UTF16 -> UnicodeFFFE

        Row rowExcelEncoding    = bqCommon.GetSystemParameters( Constants.SYS_PARAM_EXCEL_ENCODING );

        if ( rowExcelEncoding.HasField( "SYPM_AlphaNum_Val_2" ) && Convert.ToString( rowExcelEncoding[ "SYPM_AlphaNum_Val_2" ]) != ""  )    {

            string  strEncoding = Convert.ToString( rowExcelEncoding[ "SYPM_AlphaNum_Val_2" ] );

            if ( !strEncoding.Equals( Constants.EXCEL_ENCODING_DEFAULT ) )  strEncodingWebName = strEncoding;

            Encoding    objEncoding = Encoding.Default;

            try {

                objEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding( strEncodingWebName );

            }
            catch ( Exception objSysEx )    {
                throw   new FANUCApplicationException( "CM13641", objSysEx );
            }

            Response.ContentEncoding    = objEncoding;
            EnableViewState             = false;


            string  strPath         = Server.MapPath( @"..\Temp" );

            string  strFileName     = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xls";

            string  strFullFilePath = strPath +  @"\" + strFileName;



            StreamWriter    objStrmWrtr = new StreamWriter( strFullFilePath, false, objEncoding );

            objStrmWrtr.Write( strReport );

            objStrmWrtr.Close();

            Response.Redirect( "../Temp/" + strFileName );
            Response.End();
        }
        else
            throw new FANUCApplicationException( "CM13631" );
    }
```

Update:
Actually never mind. Turns out, there is no problem with the code. Excel is using the system's regional settings to get the date format. And on my system, it is set to dd-mm-yy (default format used by us). Changing the format in the system setting makes it work.

Although, I would like to overwrite this behavior. I can't expect users to change region settings on the PC. So, now, a different question. Is there a way to overwrite this behavior specifically for this streamwriter or this page?

Comment: Do you try to set current culture (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) in en-GB?

Comment: Not that I recall, no. BTW, even if I set the current culture to en-GB, it should still convert the date based on the value from cell. So, converting YYYY-mm-dd to mm-dd-yy should not be confusing.

Comment: TLDR http://sscce.org/